Get the previous State of Check box React
I’m working on a React Front End project where users can fill in form fields (including textboxes, check boxes, and select boxes). Here’s the scenario:
In the initial state, the user fills in the name, age, and nationality, and checks the checkbox.
Upon clicking “Save,” all the entered data is saved as a JSON file, stored with a variable name.
these values stored in the backed end with the End Point /read-value/
Later, when the user wants to refill the fields, they select a name from a drop-down.
The goal is to automatically populate the form fields (name, age, nationality,single) based on the selected name from the JSON data.
The issue I’m facing is that even though  the other text fields are getting populated as expected but not the checkbox ,the checkbox value is saved as true in the JSON file,but it doesn’t automatically check when refilling the form.
How can I ensure that the checkbox state reflects the saved value from the JSON data when refilling the form?
I tried this code:
function SaveForm({ selectedName }){
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    nationality: '',
    age: '',
    single: false,  
  });
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = React.useState(false);

  const fetchDefault = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(${apiUrl}/read-value/);
    const newData = await response.json();
    
    setResults(newData.results)
   
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setFormData(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      
      ["name"]: selectedName,
    
    }));
   fetchDefault()
   // setFormData(formData.name)
  }, [selectedName])

  const setFormDefaults =(data)=>{
    setFormData(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      ["name"]: data.name,
      ["nationality"]:data.nationality,
      ["age"]:data.age,
      ["single"]: data.single ,
    }));
  }
  const handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ServiceSelect results={results} setFormData={setFormDefaults}/>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Checkbox 
        name="single" 
        value ={ formData.single}  
        onValueChange={setIsSelected} 
        onChange={handleChange} 
        >single</Checkbox>
         <br></br>


Can you elaborate on what you mean/are trying to do. Right now your question is a bit vague. At what point of the execution are you "trying to get the previous value" of the checkbox? Do you mean the previous value right before they changed it, or the previous value as in what it was when the form initially loaded?

Agreed. What do you mean by "previous". The previous value of a checkbox will just be the opposite of what it is now.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I edit the description hope it is  clear now

//<data.single == json value for your checkbox, (true or false if i understand correctly..) from the json object 'data'
if (data.single){
    <yourcheckbox>.setAttribute('checked' 'true');
};


Thanks everyone for your help,Finally I found the answer that i need :
<Checkbox 
      
      name="single"
      isSelected={formData.single}
      onValueChange={(value) => {
        handleChange({
          target: {
            name: 'single',
            value: value,
          },
        });
      }}
        
        >single</Checkbox>

